# confused with bytes, blocks, en-/decoding in c++

Tags: c++, byte

I have a 64-byte block and want to append a 64 Bit (8 Byte) Block of data at the end.

```
typedef unsigned char uint1; // 1 Byte
typedef unsigned int uint4; // 4 Byte

// The 64 Byte-Block:
int BLOCKSIZE=64;
static uint1 padding[BLOCKSIZE] = {
        0x80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
};
// [[10000000][00000000].........[00000000]]


// The 64 Bit (8 Byte-Block):
uint4 appendix[2] = {};
appendix[1] = 0x000000ff;
// [[00000000000000000000000000000000][00000000000000000000000011111111]]
```

after memcpy 8 bytes from appendix to the last 8 byte of padding

```
memcpy(&padding[56], &appendix, 8);
```

it looks like

```
static uint1 padding[BLOCKSIZE] = {
        0x80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xff, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };
```

but shouldn't it look like this?

```
static uint1 padding[BLOCKSIZE] = {
        0x80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xff
    };
```

I don't know whats wrong here!?!?

Can you help me?

Comment: What is `uint1`? C does not support bit-addressable objects. And do not add C tag for C++ questions! These are different languages.

Comment: sorry, I corrected my questions

Comment: You are on little-endian platform and int is saved LSB first (i.e. bottom byte first).

BTW, use long or uint32_t for 4-byte integer, not int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
appendix[1] = 0x000000ff;
// [[00000000000000000000000000000000][00000000000000000000000011111111]]
```

You're making assumptions about the byte order (endianness). You can't make such assumptions. Depending on byte-order of the architechture, `appendix` could alternatively be represented like this:

```
// [[00000000000000000000000000000000][11111111000000000000000000000000]]
```

If you want to set the last byte specifically, then you need to operate on *bytes*, not multi-byte integers. Like this for example:

```
uint1 appendix[8] = {};
appendix[7] = 0xff;
```

If you indeed need the last 8 bytes to represent two 4 byte integers, your code is correct in that regard and only your assumption about what the memory should look like is wrong.

If the integer must be in a particular byte order for sending it over network, then you must convert it appropriately. POSIX provides `htonl` and it's sister functions for exactly that. The functions are also provided by msvc.

You're also making the assumption that `unsigned int` is 4 bytes. It's not guaranteed to be. Use `int32_t` instead if you need a 4 byte integer.

Update:

> My Goal is to implement MD5 and I need to append a 64 bit representation of the length of a file.

According to [rfc1321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321):

> ... a sequence of
> bytes can be interpreted as a sequence of 32-bit words, where each
> consecutive group of four bytes is interpreted as a word with the
> low-order (least significant) byte given first.

MD5 is little endian. Therefore writing a 2*4 array without converting the byte order will work correctly only on a little endian processor.

I recommend using a 8*1 byte-array so that you can control the order of the bytes exactly as the specification requires. Alternatively, if you're on linux or another platform that provides them, you could use `htole32` and `le32toh` functions to convert to the correct byte order. On another platform you may need to implement them yourself.

Comment: ok, thx. My problem is that i don't know which is the right thing. I'm really confused now. My Goal is to implement MD5 and I need to append  a 64 bit representation of the length of a file. If there is abetter way than using a 2*4 byte array to to this, please let me know. Actually i will try both ways. First, a 2*4 byte array and a 64 bit integer. I try out both and compare the results after appending.

Comment: so what is the right binary expression, if i have a file with 8 byte size, stored in a 64 bit integer? Ithink it is: [000000(56 zeros).........01000000] and the 8*1 Byte representation should look like this: [00000000][00000000]...[01000000], right??

Comment: @tbol that's what the byte representation should look like in big endian byte order.

Comment: okay, thank you. Now i know MD5 is little endian and i have to decode into a form that ist right for md5 (little endian). Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

So, as far as I'm able to understand the RFC1321 I need a 64 Bit Integer representation of the original message (file) size. The file size is 64 Byte. In a 64 Bit Integer the value 64 is in binary either:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000
```

or:

```
0000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I have decoding funcitons for both, but i don't know which is right for md5 ?

Comment: why degrading my answer? Sorry, that I haven' understand all at the first time :/

Answer (score -2):

You should look at [Endianless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Your option is big-endian here.